# Python3 Pandas - Create new DataFrame based on array of objects

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have an array of objects. I'm trying to loop through that array and create a new dataframe, then save that to a spreadsheet.

My object variables are like this:

```
def __init__(self, question, total):
    self.question = str(question)
    self.total = float(total)
    self.answers = {}
```

`question` is a string of the question text

`total` is a number of the total votes the question received

`answers` is a dictionary containing data like: `{'Yes': 5, 'No': 2, 'Maybe': 1}`, a string for the answer choice and a number for the number of votes an answer received

I am trying to loop through the `q_array` of `Question` objects, append the question and total, then in a for loop below go through the answer items and append those on additional rows.

Here's the desired output/sheet:

```
Question                Answer    Total    Percent
What color is the sky?            22       
                        Red       8        36.4%
                        Green     2        9.1%
                        Blue      12       54.5%
```

Here's my current code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx')

sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Question', 'Answer', 'Total', 'Percent'))
for data in q_array:
    sdf.append({'Question': data.get_question(), 'Total': data.get_total()}, ignore_index=True)
    for answer, number in data.get_answers().items():
        sdf.append({'Answer': answer, 'Total': number, 'Percent': number_to_percent(number, data.get_total())}, ignore_index=True)

sdf.to_excel(writer, 'stats', index=False)

writer.save()
```

I'm trying to use `.append()` to add the new rows and select what data goes in the row. But when I print `sdf` it's empty and in the spreadsheet it has the columns but the rest of the data is missing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple: instead of `sdf.append()` I needed to set the DataFrame equal to the append, therefore `sdf = sdf.append()`

Here's the correct code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx')

sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Question', 'Answer', 'Total', 'Percent'))
for data in q_array:
    sdf = sdf.append({'Question': data.get_question(), 'Total': data.get_total()}, ignore_index=True)
    for answer, number in data.get_answers().items():
        sdf = sdf.append({'Answer': answer, 'Total': number, 'Percent': number_to_percent(number, data.get_total())}, ignore_index=True)

sdf.to_excel(writer, 'Stats', index=False)

writer.save()
```